# Azure linux VM inbound rules not working for custom port

Tags: linux, azure

I have a linux (CentOS 7) vm on my azure account. I opened port 20212 in both inbound and outbound rules, but when i try telnet i get the following message: 
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused 
[UPDATE]
Maybe a little more clarification on my problem. I am trying to open port 20212 for a java program that is on the vm. So am trying to connect using a java socket and here is the error i get where i run my program : 
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed) 
This error is because the port is refusing connection!

Comment: Do you check whether the port is listening `netstat -ant|grep 20212`

Comment: Could you `telnet 127.0.0.1 20212` on your VM?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT netstat -ant|grep 20212 doesn't return anything

Comment: @Walter-MSFT when i tried telnet 127.0.0.1 20212 i got connection refused again. Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

Comment: Please check your app's log, your app does not start

Comment: Yes, it's not NSG's issue. You should check your app firstly.

Comment: Do you ensure the service listening on 20212? Maybe you could use `netstat -ant` to check which services are listening.

Comment: It's probably my app, Let me check it and i'll get back to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that firewalld is not blocking access to the port ?
try `firewall-cmd --add-port=20121/tcp`. But be aware that this setting does not survive a reboot unless you execute `firewall-cmd --add-port=20121/tcp --permanent` as well.